# Python Pandas : return multiple columns value based on descending limit 1 of most repeated value of a selected column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe which is as follows,

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'mac':['ac233f26492b'], 
                   'location':[['L','K','L','W-2']], 
                   'payload':[['LP','KP','LP','LW-2']], 
                   'type':[['iBeacon','others','iBeacon','others']], 
                   'ssi':[[[-43,-54,-72],[-76,-72,-78],[-49,-51,-76],[-52,-59,-54]]] }])
```

Now I need to find the most repeated value from a column "location". Based on the result of "location" column, the respective index of value has to be return for the columns like "payload", "type" & "ssi".

The outcome suppose to be,

```
df:
  mac          location payload type    ssi
0 ac233f26492b L        LP      iBeacon [-49,-51,-76]
```

- The most repeated value of "location" column are in indices 0 & 3
- The top most index from the "location" column has to be considered to return the values for " payload", "type" & "ssi"
- Everything should be based on group key i.e., "mac" column here

I have tried with

```
for index,row in df.iterrows():
    location = max(((item, row['location'].count(item)) for item in set(row['location'])),
                                  key=lambda a: a[1])[0]
    df.loc[index, "location"] = location
```

Whereas, I dont know how to derive the values for rest of the columns like "payload", "type" & "ssi". Can anyone please help me out to get the values for "payload", "type" & "ssi" based on the returned value of "location" column?

Answer (score 0):

in your example there are 2 unique ssi for same Location.How do you decide which ssi to choose?

Comment: The most repeated values of "location" column are in "index 0" and "index 3". The top descending value is "index 3" from "location" column. So the "index 3" of "payload", "type" & "ssi" column should be considered as its value.